“0 edit suggestions canceled” in review stats: what is that used for, is it not same as “rejected edit”?

I recently saw this in any of my edits in the “editor stats”:

user1176409 had 95 edit suggestions approved, 10 edit suggestions rejected, and 0 edit suggestions canceled.

I was surprised when I saw the “suggestion canceled”. I didn’t see that before, I think maybe it is a new feature.
Question: What is this “suggestion canceled” used for? Is it not the same thing as “suggestion rejected” (i.e. Does “suggestion canceled” count towards the “edits ban”)? Can anyone clarify?

See this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430836/3301540

"canceled" suggested edits happen when a suggested edit conflicts with a unilateral edit made after the suggested edit was made.
This is a recent change; it went live yesterday as part of the "Community Asks" development sprint.
In theory, these shouldn't count toward a suggestion ban. If you notice that they are for some reason counting towards a ban, a bug report is probably in order.
